# Which analytical reagent can be used to detect Vinca alkaloids?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, alkaloids

I am commencing a project on increasing the sensitivity of screening of some bioactive compounds produced as secondary metabolites from the plants! All of its chemical struture is known which is a dimer of vindoline ring connected to a catantine ring through carbon-carbon analysis! However there are no reagents specified in any research papers which could specifically bind with this compound to help in its quantitative analysis! Do I have to predict the reagent according to its chemical structure or is there some specific analytical reagent which can provide a detectable reaction with it?